# How to patch dynamic imports in python unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have the below file structure in my project. The magic basically contains wrappers around the third-party libraries.

```
.
├── magic
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── mock.py
│   └── real.py
```

So based on environment variables, we import methods from either `mock.py` entirely or `real.py`. Now I want to write unit tests for some methods which use these magic methods from `magic`. The contents of `__init__.py` are listed below.

```
if SOME_ENV:
    from .mock import (
        magic_method
    )
else:
    from .real import (
        magic_method
    )

__all__ = [
    "magic_method"
]
```

In unit tests, when I want to patch them and see whether `magic_method` was called, I am always getting it like `magic_method` was never called, but it is called every time if I run the script. Below is the sample `test_case()`

```
def test_magic(db):
    with patch("magic.mock.magic_method") as magic_method:
        # something
    assert magic_method.called
```

The above test is failing every time. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are importing `magic_method` into `magic` (`from xxx import magic_method`), so you have to patch that method: `patch("magic.magic_method")`.

Comment: Yes I tried it too @MrBeanBremen but it didn't work

Comment: Well, it depends on what you do in "something" and how `magic_method` is imported there.